# Copying Group Instance Computation Expense

Tags: python, instances

I am pushing into the scene around 38k to 50k cube instances using Python, however, I am reasonably expecting to finish the execution of the code within ten minutes or so, I am OK with an hour at most. But it's taking 11h to finish.

Here the code where I placing the cube Instances

```
for l in localizations:
        i = 0
        buffer = []
        gens = random.randint(6, 16)
        probability = np.random.uniform(.1, .8, 1)
        status = initial_status(gens, probability)
        
        while np.all((status) == 0) == False:
            status = make(status)
            buffer.append(status)  
            
            if len(buffer) > 5:
                buffer.pop(0)  
                
            for j in range(len(status[0])):
                for k in range(len(status[1])):
                    
                    if status[j, k] == True and len(bpy.context.scene.objects) == 1:                        
                        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=1, 
                                                        location=(l[0]+j, l[1]+k, i), 
                                                        scale=(1, 1, 1))
                        mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Material")
                        mat1 = bpy.data.materials.get("Material.001")
                        
                        for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
                            if ob.name.startswith("Cube"):
                                ob.data.materials.append(mat)  
                            if ob.name.startswith("Plane"):
                                ob.data.materials.append(mat1)
                                                     
                        bpy.ops.collection.create(name="cubes")
                        
                    if status[j, k] == True and len(bpy.context.scene.objects) > 1:  
                        bpy.ops.object.collection_instance_add(collection='cubes', 
                                                               location=(l[0]+j, l[1]+k, i), 
                                                               scale=(1, 1, 1))
            i+=1
```

Whether I push `mesh.primitive` or `instance` it gets slower exponentially. I couldn't understand this, to be honest.

in the function call 'make' has 2 * `np.where`, one multiply op. and one sum op. of two arrays. That mean, basically has no mentionable effect on computational cost. In addition all the arrays dims that two nested loop checking element by element are max 16x16, which also as small as not even mention it. One more extra question is: In the "Current file" section in Blender's right panel, there is let say 40k object in objects folder seperately, and also in scene sections; scene collection and object section has 40k element both. Totally there shows 120k but three copy of same elements. Does this make sense?

Thanks in advance, stay positive.

Comment: Calling multiple operators per loop how many times? see Issues related to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163796/how-can-i-efficiently-duplicate-a-large-amount-of-objects  (particularly part re using operators in a loop [Possible dupe](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators)) Consider  dupliverts  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163796/how-can-i-efficiently-duplicate-a-large-amount-of-objects  or  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/61254/15543 for making an array (eg make mesh  array and dupli) if result is array.

Comment: like I've said; one 'multiply operation' per loop. basically I automated this operation: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCpsAcNBEa4), In the code I've just using `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add` one times if the all scene has only one object that is the plane itself, I am adding it from out of the loop. rest of the cubes are just copied version of the collection.

Comment: To reiterate calling operators many times is going to be slow. How many operators are you calling altogether?   Hard to know given no idea re the unknown variables used but not defined  in question code. `bpy.ops.object.collection_instance_add` is also an operator (and is  unrequired can all  be done via  API methods)

Comment: I am just calling `bpy.ops.object.collection_instance_add` approx 30k to 50k times, because that much of cubes I need in the scene. rest of the code do not have any effect on the computation as I mentioned it. The make function has just one summation and one multiplication and 2 np.where, which is condition. When you run np.dot(arr(16x16), arr(16x16)) million times it takes 1 sec or so. so no effect. if you must know len(localization) is around 60, while loop continues until all the arrays elements converges to 0, and pushes the cubes at the location where arrays element is grater than 0.

Comment: Lol "just"..... To reiterate calling an operate 30K times is going to be slow, try it (numpy-less)  `for i in range(30000): bpy.ops.some.operator()`  IMO this is a confirming. [Python performance with blender operators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators)  _It pertains to any blender operator_

Comment: well this is my second day in the school. So, I can call the ops 50k times an I can complain about it, thanks for helping btw, I've solved it I presume. I've couldn't understand the copy idea at first because in the docs refers to it as copying the id, after your insistence on, I finally get the idea.

Comment: Quite likely dupliverts is going to be quickest. Make a mesh with verts at locs from code above parent single created group to it.

Comment: yep! now I can push 10k in 6 sec so, it is working.